# How to queue RPC requests in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I am using GWT for my web application. I have three RPC requests to server methods. I am calling these functions one after the other in Client side. I am not able to get results for all three functions. I know that asynchronous requests are made to server methods and order of execution may not be same as the order in which methods are called. But I am not able to get result for one of the methods. Will queueing RPC requests solve the problem ?

Comment: Let me just consult my crystal ball... ;) No, seriously, you have to give more details, currently it's not even clear what's the problem - what does "not able to get result for one of the methods" mean? An exception? A timeout? Please add more details so that someone can actually help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the question is not at all clear,GWT-RPC is one of the approach to communicate Client to Server,Client is never blocked during communication.

**Yes** you need maintain a queue like let say you have two request LoginInfo Request  and LoginAuth Request then first call LoginInfo Request then onSuccess of LoginInfo call LoginAuth Request,

```
service.LoginInfo(new AsyncCallback() {
 public void onSuccess(Void result) {
      // services.LoginAuth(new AsyncCallback(){.....
    }
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
      // do some UI stuff to show failure
    }
  };
```